# Mottie's Virtual Keyboard close on validate true

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, virtual-keyboard

I am using the jQuery on-screen keyboard plugin with a touchscreen.
On my input I want to close the keyboard when I have reached 4 characters.
Unfortunately, the keyboard only know when I have reached 4 characters and can limit the maximum input to 4 characters.
The user still has to close manually the keyboard.
Is there a code to close the keyboard ?
Here is my actual script :

```
$('#password').keyboard({
        layout: 'custom',
        customLayout: {
            'default' : [
                'C D E F',
                '8 9 A B',
                '4 5 6 7',
                '0 1 2 3',
                '{bksp} {a} {c}'
            ]
        },
        usePreview : false,
        autoAccept: true,
        maxLength : 4,
        // Prevent keys not in the displayed keyboard from being typed in
        restrictInput : true,
        // include lower case characters (added v1.25.7)
        restrictInclude : 'a b c d e f',
        // don't use combos or A+E could become a ligature
        useCombos : false,
        // activate the "validate" callback function
        acceptValid : true,
        validate : function(keyboard, value, isClosing){
            // only make valid if input is 4 characters in length
            if(value.length === 4)
                return true; // I want to close the keyboard here

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I was going to suggest adding a `setTimeout` in the `change` callback, but then I noticed javascript errors popping up because the keyboard was closing and the "keyup" event was still firing.

Anyway, I fixed those errors and added a new [`autoAcceptOnValid` option](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Usability#autoacceptonvalid) - use it as follows ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/egb3a1sk/1518/)):

```
$(function() {

  $('#password').keyboard({
    layout: 'custom',
    customLayout: {
      'default': [
        'C D E F',
        '8 9 A B',
        '4 5 6 7',
        '0 1 2 3',
        '{bksp} {a} {c}'
      ]
    },
    usePreview: false,
    autoAccept: true,
    maxLength: 4,
    // Prevent keys not in the displayed keyboard from being typed in
    restrictInput: true,
    // include lower case characters (added v1.25.7)
    restrictInclude: 'a b c d e f',
    // don't use combos or A+E could become a ligature
    useCombos: false,
    // activate the "validate" callback function
    acceptValid: true,
    // option added in v1.25.29
    autoAcceptOnValid: true,
    validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing) {
      return value.length === 4;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: what if I want to launch a javascript function after the keyboard is closed ?

Comment: Bind to the [`hidden` event](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Methods#events).